# docker-compose doesn't bind volume correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have .NET Core 3.0 application which is running in Docker container. I want to store application logs outside the container and so i am trying to configure my docker-compose file to mount my application logs folder **/app/log** from container to **/var/log** path on my host. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  shikimoritelegrambot:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}shikimoritelegrambot
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ShikimoriTelegramBot/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/log:/app/log
```

Here is my DOCKERFILE for project:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ShikimoriTelegramBot/ShikimoriTelegramBot.csproj ShikimoriTelegramBot/
RUN dotnet restore ShikimoriTelegramBot/ShikimoriTelegramBot.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/ShikimoriTelegramBot
RUN dotnet build ShikimoriTelegramBot.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ShikimoriTelegramBot.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShikimoriTelegramBot.dll"]
```

Here is link to my repository with code: https://github.com/otsomkalov/ShikimoriTelegramBot

Here is output of **docker inspect** command: https://pastebin.com/Dr1iMgPF

Actual result: 
I can see my logs in /app/log container folder. In /var/log folder of host machine logs are missing.

Expected result:
I can find my logs file in /var/log folder of host machine.

Comment: How are you running this? The README in your github says **docker run** which should be **docker-compose run**

Comment: @NickRundle thx, your comment solved my problem. If you want you can move it to answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
docker-compose run
```

instead of `docker run`.

The difference is that docker-compose automatically sets up the volumes in the compose file among other things.  Essentially, it is a wrapper around the docker cli.